# Error assigning variable type using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, textarea

I'm trying to assign a number to a variable by using a jQuery function that tests some text from a textarea against some regex. It does not currently assign the value to 'i'. I can only assume that my brackets are incorrectly placed.

For bonus 'points' (I got none, seriously) can someone tell me the correct way to assign any variable using jQuery

This answer helped me but not with the jQuery : [Javascript: How many times a character occurs in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903542/javascript-how-many-times-a-character-occurs-in-a-string)

Here is the code :

```
var i = $('#Input').text().match(/a/g).length;

$('button').click( function() {
    alert(i);
});
```

*Alert is there just so I can check if it did it or not*

Comment: Try `$('#Input').val().match(/a/g).length`. Form elements don't have text, they have value.

Comment: Thanks :) Should've thought of that :)
Will I be testable against regex then?

Comment: var i = $('#Input').val();

$('button').click( function() {
    i.match(/a/g).length;
    alert(i);
});
This isn't working now :/

Comment: `var length = i.match(/a/g).length; alert(length);`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/qrvj2ohx/ isn't working :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qrvj2ohx/1/

Comment: Thanks! As soon as you did it I'd just worked it out! thanks for being so helpful though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `val()` instead of `text()` as shown below:

```
var i = $('#Input').val().match(/a/g).length;
```