# Calculate spaces in string using Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

I am working on a book and it is asking to create a **function** to find the spaces in a string. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but here is the code I have.

```
function calSpaces(str) {
  var spaces = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === ' ') {
       spaces ++;
  }
  return spaces - 1;
}

console.log(calSpaces("This is a test of spaces."));
```

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: i think it should be just return spaces;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How many times a character occurs in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903542/javascript-how-many-times-a-character-occurs-in-a-string)

Comment: Not a duplicate; needed help in a function format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your braces, one is missing

```
function calSpaces(str) {
  var spaces = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === ' ') {
       spaces ++;
  }//end of IF
  return spaces - 1;
}//end of FOR
//??? end of FUNCTION ???
console.log(calSpaces("This is a test of spaces."));
```

You were using `return` inside your `for` loop.

You only need to return `spaces` not `spaces - 1`

```js
function calSpaces(str) {
  var spaces = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === ' ') {
      spaces++;
    }
  }
  return spaces;//Outside of loop
}


console.log(calSpaces("This is a test of spaces."));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one trick like this:

```
var st = "Good morning people out there."
var result = st.split(' ');
var space_count = result.length-1;
console.log( space_count );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is working but you just miss one curly bracket in if condition.

```
function calSpaces(stringline)
{
  var spaces = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < stringline.length; i++) 
  {
    if (stringline[i] === ' ') {
       spaces ++;
    }
  }
  return spaces - 1;
}
```

Just add ending curly bracket and problem solved.

Also, returning space have `total count - 1`. is this intentionally done? if not then please remove `- 1` from the count.

Here is the [JSBIN link](https://jsbin.com/henalajute/edit?js,console,output)

happy coding.

Comment: It was intentionally done but not needed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple solution is to use regex that will match spaces (and/or all whitespaces):

```js
function countSpaces(str) {
  return (str.match(/\s/g) || []).length;
}

function showCount() {
  var str = document.getElementById('string').value;
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = countSpaces(str);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="string">
<button onclick="showCount()">Count Spaces</button>
<span id="count"></span>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the question, it would probably benefit from a short explanation as to what you are doing, for example, explaining it uses regex to solve the problem, and maybe showing some output in the form of a stack snippet. - From Review.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```
 var my_string = "This is a test of spaces.";
 var spaceCount = (my_string.split(" ").length - 1);
 console.log(spaceCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is using regex to extract only the spaces from the string and count them:

```js
function calSpaces(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^\s]/g, '').length;
}

console.log(calSpaces("This is a test of spaces."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest and shortest solution would be to use `split()` and get the length of an array:

```js
var string = "This statement has lot of spaces and this spaces are never ending.";
var count = (string.split(' ').length - 1);
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways of doing that as other answers point out, but to answer your question on your exact problem: your parentheses are wrong. Try this snippet, now it works:

```js
function calSpaces(str) {
      var spaces = 0;
    
      for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === ' ') {
           spaces++;
       }
      }

      return spaces - 1;
    }

    console.log(calSpaces("This is a test of spaces."));
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest an easier/faster approach using regex:

```js
function calSpaces(str) {
    count = (str.match(/\s/g) || []).length;
    return count;
}

console.log(calSpaces('This is an example string'));
```