# Check how many times a char appears in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Simply trying to find how many times a given character appears in a string but I can't solve it any other way then this simple for-loop. Is there a method that would solve this quicker or  more eloquently other than using Regex?

```
function countCharacter(str, char) {

  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str.charAt(i) === char)
      count++;
  }
 return count;
}
```

Comment: the whole body of your function can be replaced with `return str.split(char).length - 1;` - bonus, you can search for occurrence of strings in string :p

Comment: More eloquently - yes, there's always potential for abstraction. Quicker - no, you can't get around looking at every character of the string.

Comment: You can change `str.charAt(i)` to `str[i]` to keep essentially the same algorithm with fewer function calls. *"other than using Regex"* - Why not regex?

Comment: you can't be faster than O(n) here, because you have to turn every stone exactly once. I like to keep it simple like your code, I consider other fancy ways to be a show-off :D

Comment: You can't get faster than O(n), but constants matter a lot, especially for JS where native code can be much faster than interpreted. See my answer for performance tests if speed is your main concern

Comment: Duplicated question and already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903542/javascript-how-many-times-a-character-occurs-in-a-string

Answer (score 5):

There are many possible ways are available in the market.
I am adding a few of them.

Method 1:

```
str = "The man is as good as his word"
str.split('a')
output: (4) ["The m", "n is ", "s good ", "s his word"]
str.split('a').length - 1
output: 3
```

Method 2:

```
str = "The man is as good as his word"
str.split('').map( function(char,i)
    { if(char === 'a') 
        return i;
    } 
).filter(Boolean)
Output: (3) [5, 11, 19]

str.split('').map( function(char,i)
    { if(char === 'a') 
        return i;
    } 
).filter(Boolean).length

ouput: 3
```

Edit: As per comment we can also make use of filter().

```
    str.split('').filter(function(char, i){
        if(char == 'a'){
            return i;
        }
    })
    output: (3) ["a", "a", "a"]

str.split('').filter(function(char, i){
    if(char == 'a'){
        return i;
    }
}).length
output: 3
```

Comment: Why would you use `.map()` and not just `.filter()` on its own?

Answer (score 1):

----edited by adding more cases from answers----

there are several ways, you can use split/for/regex/reduce/indexOf like this:

```
function countCharacter_reduce(str, ch) {
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(str, (prev, cur) => cur === ch && ++prev && prev, 0);
}

function countCharacter_split(str, ch) {
  return str.split(ch).length - 1;
}

function countCharacter_for(str, ch) {
  for (var count = 0, ii = 0; ii < str.length; ii++) {
    if (str[ii] === ch)
      count++;
  }
  return count;
}

function countCharacter_regex(str, ch) {
  return str.length - str.replace(new RegExp(ch, 'g'), '').length;
}

function countCharacter_indexOf(str, char) {
  var start = 0;
  var count = 0;
  while ((start = str.indexOf(char, start) + 1) !== 0) {
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

performance of them by running 1,000,000 times on counting '/' in a string.

```
-- case1: running 1000000 times on ( 'this/is/a/path/with/extension', '/' )
countCharacter_reduce: 2389.880ms
countCharacter_regex: 496.251ms
countCharacter_split: 114.709ms
countCharacter_for: 152.012ms
countCharacter_indexOf: 90.330ms

-- case2: running 1000000 times on ( '////////////', '/' )
countCharacter_reduce: 1138.051ms
countCharacter_regex: 619.886ms
countCharacter_split: 121.945ms
countCharacter_for: 74.542ms
countCharacter_indexOf: 204.242ms
```

**Conclusion ('>' means 'has better performance'):**

**`for`|`split`|`indexOf` > `regex` > `reduce`.**

**furthermore**,
if the string contains more searching characters (like case2),

`for`>`split`>`indexOf`,

otherwise (like case1)

`indexOf` > `split` > `for`.

**BTW:** you can change the `for` `indexOf` method to fit multi-characters search (example is single character)

Comment: On Chrome 89, the for loop slightly outperforms the indexOf. jsbench link https://jsbench.me/1gkm1ma8s0/1

Answer (score 0):

I guess this involves regex which you wanted to avoid but it's pretty quick:

```
function countCharacter(str, char) {
    return str.length - str.replace(new RegExp(char,"g"),"").length;
}
```

You can also try the `str.split(char).length-1` approach suggested by Jaromanda.

Or, go all out with some fun recursion (pass `0` to startingFrom):

```
function countCharacter(str, char, startingFrom) {
    var idx = str.indexOf(char, startingFrom);
    return idx == -1 ? 0 : 1 + countCharacter(str, char, idx + 1);
}
```

You can get rid of the annoying extra argument at the cost of some efficiency:

```
function countCharacter(str, char) {
    var idx = str.indexOf(char);
    return idx == -1 ? 0 : 1 + countCharacter(str.substr(idx+1), char);
}
```

And here's a version optimized for speed (this is about 3 times faster on my browser than your original and much faster than the regex versions, according to jsperf):

```
function countCharacter(str, char) {
   var start = 0;
   var count = 0;
   while((start = str.indexOf(char, start)+1) !== 0) {
       count++;
   }
   return count;
}
```

Note that the indexOf approaches will generally be substantially faster than manually iterating through the string. See [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/count-characters)

Comment: or simply `str.match(new RegExp(char, 'g')).length` if you use RegExp - with RegExp, you need to be careful of what `char` is though

Comment: True, that's even a bit more elegant probably

Comment: Then there is `str.replace(new RegExp('[^' + char + ']','g'), '').length`. ;-) Note that *match* can never return 0, it will return *null* instead and `null.length` will throw an error. :-( So maybe `(str.match(new RegExp(char, 'g')) || []).length`.

Answer (score 0):

using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
function countCharacter(str, char) {
    return str.split('').reduce((a, x) => x === char ? ++a : a, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. One line code

```
"hello".match(new RegExp('l','g')).length
```

replace `'l'` with any char here, `new RegExp('l','g')`.

that is

```
str.match(new RegExp(char,'g')).length
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using the split() method? How about this -

```
function myFunction(str, char) {    
    return string.split(char).length - 1
}
```

Let me know what you think of this solution.

Comment: This is a copy of a fraction of the most upvoted answer. :S

Comment: Sorry. I didn't realise. I got confused with the way the most upvoted answer was written. Found this simpler. Thought maybe some simplicity could help someone understand it better.