# Regex requirement to have @ symbol only once in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to javaScript and the problem I am facing is that I have to match the `@` symbol and make sure it is allowed only once in a string. To do so I have written the following regex.

```
var regexpat=/[@]{1}/;
    if(regexpat.test(valu))
       testresults = true;
       else 
      {
            alert("Please input a valid email address!");
            testresults = false;
      }
```

My regex is working for the following input value: `abcd@abc@abc.com`.  However, if I provide the input value as `"abcd@"@abc.com` it is not throwing the alert error message.

How can I change my regex so that it will work for `"abcd@"@abc.com`?

Comment: If you're verifying an email address I suggest you search SO and you'll find lots of regex'es.

Comment: `valu.replace(/[^@]+/g, "").length == 1` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903542/javascript-how-many-times-a-character-occurs-in-a-string))

Comment: Something like (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])

Comment: However, the regex for what you're describing (to use with `test`) is `/^[^@]+@[^@]+$/`.

Comment: How on earth is it a valid js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way could also be to use the `split("@")` for this:

```js
var value = 'abcd@@';
 if(value.split("@").length === 2){
  testresults = true;
 }else{
   alert("Please input a valid email address!");
   testresults = false;
 }
```

Just split your string with `@` and since you require only one occurrence of `@` there must be an array of length 2 so you can compare the array with length 2. If the array length is greater than 2 then there are more than one occurrence of `@`

Answer (score 2):

Your regexp just tests whether there's a single `@` in the string, it doesn't reject more than one. Use:

```
var regexppat = /^[^@]+@[^@]+$/;
```

This matches an `@` that's surrounded by characters that aren't `@`.

```js
var valu;
var regexpat = /^[^@]+@[^@]+$/;

while (valu = prompt("Enter email")) {
  if (regexpat.test(valu))
    console.log(valu + " is valid");
  else {
    console.log(valu + " is invalid");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Barmar,but for the input with quotes like "abc@"@abc.com for this it should go to the else loop.I used your regex then also it's not going to the else loop.

Comment: I've added an executable snippet that shows it works. Enter `"abc@"@abc.com` into the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

E-Mail regex is much more, than just the occurence of just one @ character. This is the email-regex specified in the [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/datatypes.html#form.data.emailaddress-def) (e.g. used for `<input type="email">`):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```