# Count the occurrence of every alphabet from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have seen similar questions like this asked before, such as counting characters in a given string. However when it comes to comparing given string to the letters of the alphabet and returning an object with occurences such as:

```
const letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

const sampleString = "a bee";

const results = {
 a: 1,
 b: 1,
 c: 0,
 d: 0,
 e: 2,
 f: 0,
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce),
to count letters in the sampleString.

We start by creating a `letterMap` to specify all valid letters to be counted.

In the reduce loop, we only increment letters that are present in the letterMap, using the (c in acc) expression.

```js
const letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

const sampleString = "a bee";

const letterMap = letters.reduce((acc, c) => { 
    acc[c] = 0; 
    return acc; 
}, {});

const result = [...sampleString].reduce((acc, c) => {
    if (c in acc) acc[c]++;
    return acc;
}, letterMap);

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Here's another way, using just one loop, again using `Array.reduce()`, this assumes we don't wish to count whitespace:

```js
const letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

const sampleString = "a bee";

const result = [...letters, ...sampleString].reduce((acc, c) => {
    if (c in acc) { 
        acc[c]++;
    } else if (c.trim()) {
        acc[c] = 0;
    }
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you this answer and @KooiInc have really helped me understand Array.reduce and it has clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I like using `Object.fromEntries` for this:

```js
const sampleString = "a bee";
const result = Object.fromEntries(Array.from("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", ch => [ch, 0]));
for (let ch of sampleString) 
    if (ch in result) result[ch]++;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: if you `Object.seal(result)` before iterating over `sampleString`, it doesn't try to add characters that are not part of the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) may be an idea. So, for each letter of `letters`, use `match` (length) to determine the frequency of the letter in the given sample.

```js
const letters = `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.split(``);
const freq = (chr, sample) => (sample.match(RegExp(chr, `g`)) || []).length;
const result = letters.reduce( (acc, chr) => 
  ({...acc, [chr]: freq(chr, acc.sample)}), {sample: "a bee"});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a more undestandable way

```
const letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
const sampleString = "a bee";
results = {};
sampleString.forEach(letter=>{
   if(letters.includes(letter)) {
      if(results[letter] === undefined) results[letter]=0;
      results[letter]++;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

making the value as a key is a bad practice, because it will be hard to read, I recommend to call it what it is:

```
const letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
const tempString = "This is a string.";
let results = []
letters.forEach( char =>{
  const count = countCharacterOccurences(tempString, char)
  results.push({ alphabet: char, count })
})

function countCharacterOccurences(string, char) {
   return string.split(char).length - 1;
}

console.log(results)

//filter alphabet with value
const alphabetWithCount = results.filter( result => {
   return result.count > 0
})
console.log(alphabetWithCount)

//log alphabet only with counts
const alphabetOnlyWithCounts = alphabetWithCounts.map( alphabetWithCount => {
    return alphabetWithCount.alphabet
})

console.log(alphabetOnlyWithCounts)

//
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `.reduce()` on the letters directly and in each iteration use `RegExp()` to replace all letters that do not match the current `letter` and the count the remaining letters in the string, if any, with `.length`:

```js
const letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
const sampleString = "a bee";
const results = letters.reduce((result,letter) => ({
    ...result, 
    [letter]: sampleString.replace(new RegExp(`[^${letter}]`,'g'), "").length
}), {});

console.log( results );
```

**NOTE**:

Please note that:

```
sr.replace(new RegExp('[^a]','g'), "").length
```

for example, is equivalent to:

```
sr.replace(/[^a]/g,"").length
```

See:
[JavaScript: How many times a character occurs in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903542/javascript-how-many-times-a-character-occurs-in-a-string)