# Counting a number in given array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've developed a function that counts the number of "7" in the given array. But the problem is that it counts an element only once if it has multiple 7's. I want to calculate overall number of 7 in the array.
Note: Please describe the logic in a simple and easy to understand way as I'm a newbie in Javascript.

```
function sevenBoom(arr){
  debugger;
  let singleElement, string, includeSeven;
  let flag = false;
  let counter = 0;

  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    singleElement = arr[i];
    string = singleElement.toString();
    includeSeven = string.includes("7");
    if (includeSeven == true){
      flag = true;
      counter += 1;    
    }   
  }
  if (counter == 0){
    return "There is no 7 in the array";
  }else{
    return `Boom! There are ${counter} 7s in the array...`;
  }
}
arr = [6,7,87, 777, 107777];
sevenBoom(arr);
```

Comment: Is your expected result 1 or something else (like 9 or 4)?

Comment: If you are looking for exact same number, then use like: **arr.filter(x => x == 7).length** to get the count. answer will be 1; and for testing purpose, try adding one more 7 in arr variable. count will be 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903542/javascript-how-many-times-a-character-occurs-in-a-string gives methods for counting how many characters appear in a string. Use one instead of the code which uses 'includes'.

Answer (score 1):

Convert a given array of numbers to an array of single character strings:

```
/**
* @param {string} char - wrap the number you are seeking in quotes
* @array {array<number>} array - an array of numbers
*/
function findChar(char, array) {...

/*
.string() converts each number into a string
.map() return those strings as an array of strings
.join('') takes that array of strings and converts it into a single string
.split('') takes that single string and splits it and returns an array of single string 
characters.
*/
const chars = array.map(num => num.toString()).join('').split('')
```

Next, the array of characters is filtered vs the given number ('7') and then return the count:

```
// Returns only chars that match the given character ('7') 
const hits = chars.filter(str => str === char);
return hits.length;
```

```js
const seven = [0, 100.7, 8, 9, 55, -63, 7, 99, -57, 777];

function findChar(char, array) {
  const chars = array.map(num => num.toString()).join('').split('');
  const hits = chars.filter(str => str === char);
  return hits.length;
}

console.log(findChar('7', seven));
```

Answer (score 0):

For your data

```
const arr = [6,7,87, 777, 107777];
```

To count the occurence of no. 7 you could make use of `reduce` and `split` like so

```
const countArr = arr.map((item) => {
  return item
    .toString()
    .split("")
    .reduce((acc, curr) => (curr === "7" ? acc + 1 : acc), 0);
});
```

The result for the above `countArr` would be

```
[0, 1, 1, 3, 4]
```

which means  for `[6,7,87, 777, 107777]`, we get `[0, 1, 1, 3, 4]`

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-keldysh-9meo3j?file=/src/index.js:38-186

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the function to count the occurances of `"7"` in each number of the Array.

I have made use of a Regex `/7/g` to count the number of occurances of 7 in each string element. Find the explanation for the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/fbcPns/1).

So inside the loop, it counts the count of `"7"` in each element in the array and calculates the cumilative total inside the loop.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function sevenBoom(arr) {
    let singleElement, string, includeSeven;
    let flag = false;
    let counter = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        singleElement = arr[i];
        string = singleElement.toString();
        const count = (string.match(/7/g) || []).length;
        if (count > 0) {
            flag = true;
            counter += count;
        }
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        return "There is no 7 in the array";
    } else {
        return `Boom! There are ${counter} 7s in the array...`;
    }
}
arr = [6, 7, 87, 777, 107777];
console.log(sevenBoom(arr));
```

With the same regex, you can count the total number of `"7"` inside the array in a different way.

Join the array using `Array.join()` method to generate a single string as the output. Count the total number of `"7"` inside this string using the same regex.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function sevenBoom(arr) {
    const count = (arr.join().match(/7/g) || []).length;
    return count == 0 ? "There is no 7 in the array": `Boom! There are ${count} 7s in the array...`;
}
arr = [6, 7, 87, 777, 107777];
console.log(sevenBoom(arr));
```