# Count the elements in string

Tags: javascript

I have a string that has comma separated values. How can I count how many elements in the string separated by comma?
e.g following string has 4 elements

```
string = "1,2,3,4";
```

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurances-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript though not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

myString.split(',').length

Answer (score 8):

```
var mystring = "1,2,3,4";
var elements = mystring.split(',');
return elements.length;
```

Comment: what is string = "1,2,3,4,"; ?

Answer (score 4):

All of the answers suggesting something equivalent to `myString.split(',').length` could lead to incorrect results because:

```
"".split(',').length == 1
```

An empty string is not what you may want to consider a list of 1 item.

A more intuitive, yet still succinct implementation would be:

```
myString.split(',').filter((i) => i.length).length
```

This doesn't consider 0-character strings as elements in the list.

```
"".split(',').filter((i) => i.length).length
0

"1".split(',').filter((i) => i.length).length
1

"1,2,3".split(',').filter((i) => i.length).length
3

",,,,,".split(',').filter((i) => i.length).length
0
```

Comment: Note that browser support for arrow functions is still limited: http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions For the time being I would recommend a regular function instead

Comment: You're right @Wolph. Looks like IE11 still has a 12% marketshare globally today.

Answer (score 3):

First split it, and then count the items in the array. Like this:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(/,/).length;
```

Comment: It's not wrong, it's simply a different definition. Empty string is also a value ;) Try ",," for example.

Comment: Yes, but would you say that in most use cases a single empty string would be considered a list of 1 value? so.. the count of items in "a" equals the count of items in ""?

Comment: I wouldn't say most but definitely often enough. If there is no value you probably don't want to run the function at all

Answer (score 0):

First You need to convert the string to an array using split, then get the length of the array as a count, Desired Code here.

```
var string = "1,2,3,4";
var desiredCount  = string.split(',').length;
```