# JavaScript error: "val.match is not a function"

Tags: javascript, match

I’m using the `match` function with a Regular Expression.

The code I’m using is:

```js
if(val.match(/^s+$/) || val == "" )
```

However, it produces the following error:

> ```
> "val.match is not function"
> ```

What is the problem?

Comment: Can we see where you have defined `val`? Make sure `val` is a string: `val.toString()`. Or you can use Regex.exec to implicitly convert to a string: `/^s+$/.exec(val)`.

Comment: the val is string, just now i checking the match is working for some word and not working the some word,

Comment: Definitely make sure val is defined and a String. Also, I'm guessing it's a typo that you don't have a slash before the 's' in your regex. If that is the case you can replace your if test with "if(val.match(/^\s*$)"

Comment: Thanks for the idea Mr. Eric Wendelin, I just changed the coding like to val.toString(), that is working, i am new to javascript, if any drouble for ur work, sorry, thanks eric

Comment: No trouble at all, and you're welcome :)

Comment: Seems like this has been answered - would be nice to see Eric get the credit. Care to add it as an answer?

Comment: @Eric: That should have been an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Agreed, Tomalak. Long as problem is solved all is generally good, though :)

Answer (score 88):

I would say that `val` is not a string.

I get the

> val.match is not function

error for the following

```
var val=12; 
if(val.match(/^s+$/) || val == ""){
   document.write("success: " + val);
}
```

The error goes away if you explicitly convert to a string String(val)

```
var val=12; 
if(String(val).match(/^s+$/) || val == ""){
   document.write("success: " + val);
}
```

And if you do use a string you don't need to do the conversion

```
var val="sss"; 
if(val.match(/^s+$/) || val == ""){
   document.write("success: " + val);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was using the code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript and was getting the "is not a function" message and was going crazy!

Comment: if you need this to implement some sort of pipe transform, it is a good idea to convert the incoming values to string to make sure it works all the time. Thanks @chrisp7575

Answer (score 23):

the problem is: val is not string

i can think of two options
1) convert to string: might be a good option if you are sure val has to be string

"Same as above answer"

```js
var val=12; 
if(String(val).match(/^s+$/) || val == ""){
   document.write("success: " + val);
}
```

2) skip the line: in my case, it was better to just check the val type and skip if it is not string, because it was not a good idea to run "match" function anyways.

```js
val = 12;
if( val.match) {
  if(val.match(/^s+$/) || val == "" ) {
    document.write("success: " + val);
  }
} else {
    document.write("not a string: " + val);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: making this an answer as suggested above from my comment.

Definitely make sure val is defined and a String. Also, I'm guessing it's a typo that you don't have a slash before the 's' in your regex. If that is the case you can replace your if test with "if(val.match(/^\s*$)"

Comment: I have a similar issue, in my case, I am validating that the value is a number and not an alphabet, will converting it to string be a good idea? because when I do, the validation fails and returns an object instead of either string(error message) or boolean.