# How to count the number of lines of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I would like to count the number of lines in a string. I tried to use this stackoverflow answer,

```
lines = str.split("\r\n|\r|\n"); 
return  lines.length;
```

on this string (which was originally a buffer):

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:8888
 Connection: keep-alive
 Cache-Control: max-age=0
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
 Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

and, for some reason, I got `lines='1'`.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: @BookOfZeus "\n" and "\r" are handled by his regexp. "\n\r" is plain wrong.

Comment: oh i see it, you are right my bad

Comment: I've answered a related question, "What's the fastest way to test for a minimum number of lines or tokens?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554154/fastest-way-to-test-for-a-minimum-number-of-lines-or-tokens

Comment: @bezmax "\n\r" is necessary for pasted text.

Comment: @SupremeDolphin No it is not, at least not for the example given. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message : "The request line and other header fields must each end with <CR><LF>", that is `\r\n`.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Using a regular expression you can count the number of lines as

```
 str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length
```

Alternately you can try split method as below.

```
var lines = $("#ptest").val().split("\n");  
alert(lines.length);
```

working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/C8CaX/

Comment: Fails for this test case: `'Roomy Below:\n\nStart again.'`. It detects 3 lines, when, visually, there are 4. This is because the split merges both new lines together.

Comment: @SimplGy What? It doesn't fail. It detects 3 lines because there are 3 lines, even visually. `console.log('Roomy Below:\n\nStart again.')` gives you 3 lines. If split merged new lines, this wouldn't work: `console.log('Roomy Below:\n\nStart again.'.split('\n').join('\n'))`, but it does and you get the same 3 lines again.

Comment: You're right Jools, I messed up this re-creation case because visually that is 3 lines (the first \n ends a text line and the second one creates a blank line). I'm sure my objection was based on a real life scenario at some point but I have no idea what at this point.

Comment: If your text only takes '\n' for new-line characters(e.g. a `<textarea>`'s `value`), you can consider using `TEXT.match(/^/mg).length`.

Comment: you answer is incorrect consider case "\n\n". There is only two lines. But your code outputs 3. Which is not correct.

Comment: @Khamidulla You miscounted, "\n\n" has 3 lines, each containing an empty string. Every string (even the empty string) has 1 line, then each \n adds another line. It's really the same thing as looking at "1\n2\n3", which is the numbers 1, 2 and 3, each on their own line.

Answer (score 80):

Another short, potentially more performant than split, solution is:

```
const lines = (str.match(/\n/g) || '').length + 1
```

to avoid possible errors, it can help to convert it explicitly into a string ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/5196710/2891692 ) :

```
const lines = (String(str).match(/\n/g) || '').length + 1
```

Comment: this is way better solution

Comment: like this solution, small improvement: the `\r?` isn't actually doing anything, `(str.match(/\n/g) || '').length` produces the same result, doesn't it?

Comment: Better solution, as split function creates new array which is heavy than this solution.

Comment: both methods create a new array … str.match return an Array so does the split too …
The split method return an Array of strings, but str.match return an Array of objects.
I think an object take more space in memory than string …

Comment: clear winner in [benchmark](http://jsbench.github.io/#4cc806b4507ae063efc81900cdfb9b02)

Comment: @milahu for me split performs better :) it's surprising how bad for loop is.

Answer (score 11):

To split using a regex use `/.../`

```
lines = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
```

Comment: Same rule but quite shorter `/\r?\n/`

Answer (score 11):

Hmm yeah... what you're doing is absolutely wrong. When you say `str.split("\r\n|\r|\n")` it will try to find the exact string `"\r\n|\r|\n"`. That's where you're wrong. There's no such occurance in the whole string. What you really want is what David Hedlund suggested:

```
lines = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
return lines.length;
```

The reason is that the split method doesn't convert strings into regular expressions in JavaScript. If you want to use a regexp, use a regexp.

Answer (score 8):

I made a performance test comparing split with regex, with a string and doing it with a for loop.

It seems that the for loop is the fastest.

NOTE: this code 'as is' is not useful for windows nor macos endline, but should be ok to compare performance.

Split with string:

```
split('\n').length;
```

Split with regex:

```
split(/\n/).length;
```

Split using for:

```
var length = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < sixteen.length; ++i)
  if(sixteen[i] == s)
    length++;
```

http://jsperf.com/counting-newlines/2

Comment: funny, my [benchmark](http://jsbench.github.io/#4cc806b4507ae063efc81900cdfb9b02) says that for-loop is slowest

Answer (score 3):

There are three options:

Using jQuery (download from [jQuery website](http://www.jquery.com)) - jquery.com

```
var lines = $("#ptest").val().split("\n");
return lines.length;
```

Using Regex

```
var lines = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
return lines.length;
```

Or, a recreation of a for each loop

```
var length = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i){
    if(str[i] == '\n') {
        length++;
    }
}
return length;
```

Comment: This is not a true comment. There are not just three options.

Answer (score 2):

Better solution, as str.split("\n") function creates new array  of strings split by "\n" which is heavier than str.match(/\n\g). str.match(/\n\g) creates array of matching elements only. Which is "\n" in our case.

```
var totalLines = (str.match(/\n/g) || '').length + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for this problem using the spread operator and no regular expressions would be:

```
const lines = [...csv].reduce((a, c) => a + (c === '\n' ? 1 : 0), 0)
```

```js
const csv = `
demo_budget_2021_v4_wk_9,test,Civil,Spares,test,false,12,2021,100
demo_budget_2021_v4_wk_9,test,Civil,Spares,test,false,11,2021,100
demo_budget_2021_v4_wk_9,test,Civil,Spares,test,false,10,2021,100
demo_budget_2021_v4_wk_9,test,Civil,Spares,test,false,9,2021,100
`

const lines = [...csv].reduce((a, c) => a + (c === '\n' ? 1 : 0), 0)

console.log(lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/q2fjL/1/)

Just remove additional \r\n and "|" from your reg ex.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var multilinestr = `
        line 1
        line 2
        line 3
        line 4
        line 5
        line 6`;
      totallines = multilinestr.split("\n");
lines = str.split("\n"); 
console.log(lines.length);
</script>
```

thats works in my case

Answer (score 1):

I was testing out the speed of the functions, and I found consistently that this solution that I had written was much faster than `match`ing. We check the new length of the string as compared to the previous length.

```
const lines = str.length - str.replace(/\n/g, "").length+1;
```

```js
let str = `Line1
Line2
Line3`;
console.time("LinesTimer")
console.log("Lines: ",str.length - str.replace(/\n/g, "").length+1);
console.timeEnd("LinesTimer")
```