# Getting values from Deno stdin

Tags: deno

How can we get values from standard input in Deno?

I don't know how to use `Deno.stdin`.

An example would be appreciated.

Comment: It's as easy as this single line: `const stdin = new TextDecoder().decode(await Deno.readAll(Deno.stdin));`

Comment: Since writing the comment above, `Deno.readAll` has been deprecated and moved to https://deno.land/std/io/util.ts as `readAll`.

Comment: As for now, `Deno.readAll` has been moved to https://deno.land/std/streams/conversion.ts. `Deno.readAll` will be removed in Deno 2.0.

Answer (score 20):

We can use prompt in deno.

```
const input = prompt('Please enter input');
```

In case input has to be a number. We can use `Number.parseInt(input)`;

Answer (score 11):

`Deno.stdin` is of type [`File`](https://deno.land/typedoc/classes/deno.file.html), thus you can read from it by providing a `Uint8Array` as buffer and call `Deno.stdin.read(buf)`

```js
window.onload = async function main() {
  const buf = new Uint8Array(1024);
  /* Reading into `buf` from start.
   * buf.subarray(0, n) is the read result.
   * If n is instead Deno.EOF, then it means that stdin is closed.
   */
  const n = await Deno.stdin.read(buf); 
  if (n == Deno.EOF) {
    console.log("Standard input closed")
  } else {
    console.log("READ:", new TextDecoder().decode(buf.subarray(0, n)));
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily read a (whole) single line. For example, when stdin is redirected from a file, it will read a large block not just one line. If the line is very long, it will read less than the whole line. Also it might not necessarily read entire utf-8 runes, so it could break the text encoding.

Comment: `Property 'EOF' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'`, deno `1.34.3`

Comment: I think we must use `null` now instead of `Deno.EOF`: https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/4953

Answer (score 9):

A simple **confirmation** which can be answered with `y` or `n`:

```js
import { readLines } from "https://deno.land/std/io/buffer.ts";

async function confirm(question) {
    console.log(question);

    for await (const line of readLines(Deno.stdin)) {
        if (line === "y") {
            return true;
        } else if (line === "n") {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

const answer = await confirm("Do you want to go on? [y/n]");
```

Or if you want to **prompt the user for a string**:

```js
import { readLines } from "https://deno.land/std/io/buffer.ts";

async function promptString(question) {
    console.log(question);

    for await (const line of readLines(Deno.stdin)) {
        return line;
    }
}

const userName = await promptString("Enter your name:");
```

Comment: unfortunately, not applicable to Deno 1.0 anymore

Comment: @phil294 it was using `0.51.0` of `std`, which is already deprecated. bumped the version in the answer, it should be working now.

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution 100% pure Deno, but not intensively tested

```js
async function ask(question: string = '', stdin = Deno.stdin, stdout = Deno.stdout) {
  const buf = new Uint8Array(1024);

  // Write question to console
  await stdout.write(new TextEncoder().encode(question));

  // Read console's input into answer
  const n = <number>await stdin.read(buf);
  const answer = new TextDecoder().decode(buf.subarray(0, n));

  return answer.trim();
}

const answer = await ask(`Tell me your name? `);
console.log(`Your name is ${answer}`);
```

Parts of the above code was taken from answer of [Kevin Qian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033584/6454791)

Comment: This doesn't necessarily read whole lines, see my other comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [Input-Deno](https://deno.land/x/input@1.0.3) module. This is an example from the docs:

```js
// For a single question:
const input = new InputLoop();
const nodeName = await input.question('Enter the label for the node:');
        
// output:
        
// Enter the label for the node:
        
// Return Value:
// 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a small terminal sample to test with the Deno [TCP echo server](https://deno.land/std/manual.md#tcp-echo-server). It's something like:

```js
private input = new TextProtoReader(new BufReader(Deno.stdin));
```

```js
while (true) {
    const line = await this.input.readLine();
    if (line === Deno.EOF) {
        console.log(red('Bye!'));
        break;
    } else {
        // display the line
    }
}
```

The full project is on [Github](https://github.com/horaceho/deno-terminal/).

Answer (score 0):

To read all of the input to count lines and words:

```js
import { toArrayBuffer } from "https://deno.land/std@0.211.0/streams/mod.ts";

const inputData = new TextDecoder().decode(
  await toArrayBuffer(Deno.stdin.readable),
);

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/8488881/547223
const numberOfLines = inputData.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length;

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/18679657/547223
const numberOfWords = inputData.trim().split(/\s+/).length;

console.log(numberOfLines);
console.log(numberOfWords);
```

This would be useful if you want to create a script that e.g. reads a file content from stdin:

```
$ cat some_file.txt | util.ts
28
70
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
const userInput = window.prompt("type here: ")
```

[window.prompt on deno.land](https://deno.land/api@v1.39.2?s=prompt)

Answer (score 0):

With the switch from `Reader` to the web standard Stream API, `Deno.stdin` has a `readable` field which is a `ReadableStream`. Input from `stdin` can then be read fully as text with:

```js
const input = await new Response(Deno.stdin.readable).text();
```

Similarly, if input is json, it can be read accordingly:

```js
const input = await new Response(Deno.stdin.readable).json();
```

The more correct way to do it is a little more verbose:

```js
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
for await (const chunk of Deno.stdin.readable) {
  const text = decoder.decode(chunk);
  // do something with the text
}
```