# Adobe Script to show active Word Count

Tags: javascript, acrobat, word-count, adobe-javascript

I have a script that allows me to view the ***Character Count*** limit, and then it counts down. I would prefer to display a ***Word Count*** instead because the majority of people don't count characters. I've attached a link to the pdf I've created for that.

**http://webfro.gs/south/Adobe/Character%20Countdown.pdf**

In ***Properties*** > ***Actions*** > ***On Focus*** > ***Run a Javascript*** - I have the following script running...

`var maxlim=event.target.charLimit;
if (event.target.value.length==0)
this.getField("cntdwn").value=maxlim;`

Then, in ***Properties*** > ***Format*** > ***Custom Keystroke Script*** - I am running this Countdown script

`var value = custmMergeChange(event);
var L = value.length;
this.getField("cntdwn").value=(maxlim-L);`

Is there something out there that can display a ***Word Count*** and when the word count is reached (counting up) or it reaches zero (counting down), can the ability to type any further be stopped?

How's this possible?

Comment: You could count the number of spaces.

Comment: How? Is there a preset variable for spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the comment:

Not a preset variable per se, but there is an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript), that should help.

Try this, then.  It's directely from the Adobe forums, and answers your question more directly.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var ch = input.charAt(i);
        var str = new String("" + ch);

        if (i+1 != input.length && str === " " && "" + input.charAt(i+1) !== " "){
            wordCount++;
        }
```

Comment: My question is in regards to Javascript for Acrobat.