# Count the number of occurences of a character in a string - BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We would like to run a query that returns no of character in the given string if i have a string say : Baitul Sharaf, 105 Hill Road, Bandra (west), Mumbai
I want to count no of ',' in the above string (In above case 3)

see the reference for my question [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurances-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)
I want to achieve the same in BigQuery

Answer (score 30):

SELECT LENGTH(col) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, ',', '')) FROM TableName

Comment: Works perfectly! SELECT LENGTH(col) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, ',', '')) FROM (SELECT "Baitul Sharaf, 105 Hill Road, Bandra (west), Mumbai" col)

Comment: It works perfectly when string which occurrences you are counting has size that is equls to 1. If not then you need also divide by length of the string