# Count special characters in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following piece of code to count number of special characters in a string...somehow it does not return what i'd like

```
var sectionToCheck  = $('input').val(); //it could be any kind of string entered in an input field such as "Hello @&% everybody"
var specialChars = /^[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$/;
var allFoundCharacters = sectionToCheck.match(specialChars);
console.log(allFoundCharacters);
```

It returns a null value for the variable allFoundCharacters. Any tips please?

Comment: are we supposed to guess what `sectionToCheck ` is?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a sample input ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count the number of occurences of a character in a string in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pw7Mb/2/

Comment: also, do you want to count the chars, strip them, want a string without special chars returned?

Comment: What are NOT special characters? `a-z` and `0-9` in your case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've included ^ which matches the start of the string, and $ for the end. Your regex will only match strings *comprised entirely* of special characters.

Comment: for the sake of completeness: `var specialChars = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/gi; `

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Hope it will help you.

```
var str= "This is a string.";
```

// the `g` in the regular expression says to search the whole string rather than just find the first occurrence

```
var count = (str.match(/is/g) || []).length;

alert(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/[@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/g
```

Full code:

```js
var sectionToCheck  = "$%klds$"; 
var allFoundCharacters = sectionToCheck.match(/[@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/g);
alert(allFoundCharacters.length);//count
```