# Character Counter won't print all Characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am making a character counter as a hobby code. So far, it is working, but I have a glitch I can't seem to solve. When I write the terms "`a,b,c`", then it correctly writes `a:1 b:1 c:1`. But when I write "`a,a,c,c`", then it only writes `a:2`. I am not sure what's wrong. Here is the JavaScript portion of my code (`myFunction` is activated by a button, and `testinput.value` is the value of the textbox I am using):

```
function myFunction() {
  var occurence = document.getElementById("testinput").value;
  var cycleOne = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
    "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
  ];
  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    var counter = new RegExp(cycleOne[i], 'g');
    document.write(occurence.match(counter).length);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the document closed when this runs?  `document.write` blows away closed documents and creates a new blank open one in the same origin.

Comment: [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)  is not purposed to add content to a page in an event handler (i.e after the page has been parsed). Please use a proper DOM manipulation method instead.

Comment: For example, `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(occurrence.match(counter).length));` is DOM manipulation of the kind Teemu suggests.

Comment: Why don't you check this: [Count the number of occurences of a character in a string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript) Seems to answer your question perfectly As a side note interestingly enough using RegEx is not actually the fastest way of determining the number of chars in a string but rather using string split (again taken from the answer I cited above)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is printing only `2` because, it is failing with an error, immediately after that.

Let's consider the case when the input is `a,a,c,c`.

In the first iteration of the loop, you will be matching against `a` and then it finds two matches and it prints it.

In the second iteration, you will be matching against `b` and it is not there in the string. So `occurence.match(counter)` will be returning `null` and you are trying to get the `length` property from `null`. That is why it is throwing the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

and stops execution.

---

To fix this, you need to check if it is not `null`, before proceeding, like this

```
  var result = occurence.match(new RegExp(cycleOne[i], 'g'));
  if (result !== null) {
    console.log(result.length);    
  }
```

Comment: Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/1Lshzksr/ and fixed - https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/1Lshzksr/1/

Comment: @DaveSalomon I just avoided matching more than once in my answer :-)