# Count Space(s) in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string `"John Doe's iPhone6"`

Visually, I know that it contains 2 spaces.

How do I count spaces in a string in javascript ?

## I've tried

```
var input = this.value;
// console.log(input.count(' '));
```

Comment: What are you tried so far? (don't show the inexistent `count()` function)

Comment: use `match()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: Duplicate question which has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/881111/6015622

Answer (score 34):

Try this

```
var my_string = "John Doe's iPhone6";
var spaceCount = (my_string.split(" ").length - 1);
console.log(spaceCount)
```

Comment: the output will be 2

Comment: Number of spaces would be 2. If you want to find the number of words remove the -1.

Answer (score 11):

Use RegExp:

```
"John Doe's iPhone6".match(/([\s]+)/g).length
```

Comment: This method will be failed if your string like this "%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%   ------------by some one" %20 is space since stackoverflow won't show each the space

Comment: This will also fail if there are no spaces, because match will return `null`. Best to check for null before getting the .length

Answer (score 9):

Use split and count them less 1 (**-1**):

```
var string = "John Doe's iPhone6";
string.split(" ").length-1
```