# Count period "." in input or textbox using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I would like to know how can I count number of period in Input or textbox using jQuery or Javascript. 
For Example my value in textbox is "120.0.0."

Comment: We don't do your homework for you. Give it a try. If you can't get it to work, post what you have done and what problems you are having and we will try to help you.

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Use this statement:

```
  var length =  ("120.0.0.".match(/\./g)).length
```

You can replace 120.0.0 with your your input field value

Answer (score 1):

RegEx

```js
var temp = "127.0.0.1";
var count = (temp.match(/[.]/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function and then loop through each of the characters in the string incrementing the count if that character is a period.

```
var textBoxVal = $('#myTextBox').val();

int periodCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < textBoxVal.length; i++) {
    if (textBoxVal[i] === '.') {
        periodCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var temp = $('#test').val();
  var count = (temp.match(/\./g) || []).length;
  console.log(count);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='test' placeholder='Enter the text here.'/>
<button id='btn'>Check</button>
```