# Interview javascript foreach

Tags: javascript, big-o

Q: Write a function called countLetters which accepts a string and returns the values as the number of times the letter appears in the string.
Hi, Is there a more efficient way to solve that question?

O(n) solution, howto make it O(log n)

```js
function countLetters(str){
    var splitArr = str.toLowerCase().split("");
    var obj = {};
    var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxez";
  
    splitArr.forEach((letter)=>{
        if(letters.includes(letter)){
            if(letter in obj){
                obj[letter]++;
            } else{
                obj[letter] = 1;
               
            }
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
console.log(countLetters('Ellie'))
```

Comment: you can do `regex` instead of `letters.includes(letter)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/881147/244811

Comment: could also create an array of 26 elements and add accordingly - 
- you also have a typo where `y` should be btw...

Comment: Initialise `obj` to `{a:0, b:0, c:0, ...}` and then you don't need `.includes()`, you just need the `if(letter in obj) obj[letter]++` part without the `else`.

Comment: You can apply some optimizations, but you can't make it `O(log n)` since you still need to iterate over all elements to count occurrences. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You could use a regex to strip out all non alpha characters - `str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '').split('')`

Comment: Did someone tell you it could be O(log n)? Is that actually the complete question, or were there more restrictions on the input (e.g. “it is almost sorted and contains O(log n) distinct characters”)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't `O(log n)` as that isn't achieveable given the problem at hand. I do however think this is a more succinct solution to the problem.

```js
function countLetters(str){
  var letters = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '').split('');
  
  return letters.reduce(function (counts, letter) {
    counts[letter] = (counts[letter] || 0) + 1;
    return counts;
  }, {});
}

console.log(countLetters('Hello World!'));
```

Comment: This isn’t O(log n).

Comment: Agreed. But as has already been established from the comments on the question, O(log n) isn't possible. I was posting this more as an example as to how their solution could be improved.

Comment: @JaromandaX: `const countLetters = str => [...str.toLowerCase()].reduce((o, c) => (/[a-z]/.test(c) && (o[c] = ~~o[c] + 1), o), {});`