# How to check if a string has 3 or more decimal points using regex and no methods

Tags: javascript, regex

How to check if a string has 3 or more decimal points using regex. 
I only am wanting to use a regex pattern to solve this issue.

```
var string1 = "1.23432 12.123.1231"; // true
var string2 = "1.23432 12123.1231"; // false
```

What I thought would work but doesn't:

```
let regx2 = RegExp(/.{3,}/g);
  if(regx2.test(string1)){
    output = false;
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to know if any number in the string contains more than 3 decimal places, or do you want to know which number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: `retrun true;` might be a pain point.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the function `match`:

*This approach only counts the amount of dots regardless of the current format.*

This regex `/(\.)/g` captures the desired groups.

```js
console.log(("1.23432 12.123.1231".match(/(\.)/g) || []).length >= 3);
console.log(("1.23432 12123.1231".match(/(\.)/g) || []).length >= 3);
```

Comment: @mhodges yes, however the OP stated this: *how to check if a string has 3 or more decimal points using regex.*

Comment: Yes, could be an XY Problem, though - I have offered an alternative, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` to retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular.

```js
function hasMoreThan3OrMore(s) {
  return s.match(/\./g).length >= 3;
}

var string1 = "1.23432 12.123.1231"; // true
var string2 = "1.23432 12123.1231"; // false

console.log(hasMoreThan3OrMore(string1));
console.log(hasMoreThan3OrMore(string2));
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using Regex would be to use `String.split()` and check the length, like so:

```js
console.log("1.23432 12.123.1231".split(".").length > 3); // true
console.log("1.23432 12123.1231".split(".").length > 3); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all non `.` characters and them check the length

```js
let strs = [
  "11.11 1.111.11.1111",
  "1.1.1"
]

for (let s of strs) {
  console.log(s.replace(/[^\.]/g, '').length >= 3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RegExp.test()` returns a boolean, so you can simply return that. Fixing your typo would also clear up your error:

```
var string1 = "1.23432 12.123.1231"; // true
var string2 = "1.23432 12123.1231"; // false

let regx2 = RegExp(/.{3,}/g);

console.log(regx2.test(string1); // true
console.log(regx2.test(string2); // false
```

Comment: I am ending the function by returning true if the match returns true. The regex itself is not working properly by finding a string that has 3 or more decimals in it. I ended up figuring out the regex to make it work witch is  /^(.*\.){3,}\d+$/g.

Comment: And for ending a function with the value of the match, you can simply call `return regx2.test(string1);`

Answer (score 0):

The regex I was looking for was

```
 let regx2 = RegExp(/^(.*\.){3,}\d+$/g);
 if(regx2.test(string2)){
   console.log('testing 3 or more . :', string1);
   output = false;
 }
```

I am trying to get better on my knowledge of using regex expressions and so was looking for an answer that only uses regex without using a method. Thanks for all your help, I actually didn't even think about checking if the string contains a decimal and then checking how many times it returns.

Comment: `/^(.*\.){3,}\d+$/g.test("1.1.1.1.1")` returns true.. :)

Comment: I wanted the match to return true if the decimal point exceeded 2 in the given string so I could set a value to false;