# Common Character Count in Strings JavaScript

Tags: javascript, indexof

Here is the problem:

Given two strings, find the number of common characters between them.

For `s1 = "aabcc"` and `s2 = "adcaa"`, the output should be `3`.

I have written this code :

```js
function commonCharacterCount(s1, s2) {
  var count = 0;
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    if (s2.indexOf(s1[i]) > -1 && str.indexOf(s1[i]) == -1) {
      count++;
      str.concat(s1[i])
    }
  }

  return count;
}

console.log(commonCharacterCount("aabcc", "adcaa"));
```

It doesn't give the right answer, I wanna know where I am wrong?

Comment: are you trying to find common or different characters in the string?

Comment: This is not the same question, but the answers may help you streamline your approach and solve one issue you are having which is you are only finding the first instance of character in the string with `indexOf`: [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other more efficient answers, but this answer is easier to understand. This loops through the first string, and checks if the second string contains that value. If it does, count increases and that element from `s2` is removed to prevent duplicates.

```js
function commonCharacterCount(s1, s2) {
    var count = 0;
    s1 = Array.from(s1);
    s2 = Array.from(s2);
    
    s1.forEach(e => {
      if (s2.includes(e)) {
        count++;
        s2.splice(s2.indexOf(e), 1);
      }
    });
        
    return count;
}

console.log(commonCharacterCount("aabcc", "adcaa"));
```

Comment: @eng it isn't the most efficient and fastest answer, but in my opinion, it's the easiest to understand

Comment: can you please share your faster and more efficient one?

Comment: @eng most of the other answers are more efficient and faster

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in following steps:

1. Create a `function` that return an object. With **keys as letters** and **count as values**
2. Get that count object of your both strings in the main `function`
3. Iterate through any of the object using `for..in`
4. Check other object have the `key` of first object.
5. If it have add the least one to `count` using [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

```js
let s1 = "aabcc"
let s2 = "adcaa"

function countChars(arr){
  let obj = {};
  arr.forEach(i => obj[i] ? obj[i]++ : obj[i] = 1);
  return obj;
}


function common([...s1],[...s2]){
  s1 = countChars(s1);
  s2 = countChars(s2);
  let count = 0;
  for(let key in s1){
    if(s2[key]) count += Math.min(s1[key],s2[key]);
  }
  return count
}
console.log(common(s1,s2))
```

Comment: @eng accept the answer if you are satisfied with it

Answer (score 2):

After posting the question, i found  that i havent looked the example well. i thought it wants unique common characters ..
and i changed it and now its right

```js
function commonCharacterCount(s1, s2) {
    var count = 0;
    var str="";
    for(var i=0; i<s1.length ; i++){
        if(s2.indexOf(s1[i])>-1){  
            count++;
            s2=s2.replace(s1[i],'');
        }
    }                   
        
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Create 2 objects containing characters and their count for strings s1
  and s2
- Count the common keys in 2 objects and return count - Sum the common keys with minimum count in two strings
- O(n) - time and O(n) - space complexities

```
    function commonCharacterCount(s1, s2) {

        let obj1 = {}
        let obj2 = {}

        for(let char of s1){

            if(!obj1[char]) {

                obj1[char] = 1

            } else

                obj1[char]++

        }

        for(let char of s2){

            if(!obj2[char]) {

                obj2[char] = 1

            } else

                obj2[char]++

        }

        console.log(obj1,obj2)

        let count = 0

        for(let key in obj1 ){

            if(obj2[key])

                count += Math.min(obj1[key],obj2[key])
        }

        return count


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a easier way to understand. :)

```
function commonCharacterCount(s1: string, s2: string): number {
    
    let vs1 = [];
    let vs2 = [];
    let counter = 0;
    
    vs1 = Array.from(s1);
    vs2 = Array.from(s2);
    
    vs1.sort();
    vs2.sort();
    
    let match_char = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < vs1.length; i++){
        
        for(let j = 0; j < vs2.length; j++){
            
            if(vs1[i] == vs2[j]){
                match_char.push(vs1[i]);
                vs2.splice(j, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
    
    return match_char.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript ES6 clean solution. Use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

```js
var commonCharacterCount = (s1, s2) => {
  const result = [];
  const reference = [...s1];
  let str = s2;

  for (const letter of reference) {
    if (str.includes(letter)) {
      result.push(letter);
      str = str.replace(letter, '');
    }
  }

  // ['a', 'a', 'c'];
  return result.length;
};

// Test:
console.log(commonCharacterCount('aabcc', 'adcaa'));
console.log(commonCharacterCount('abcd', 'aad'));
console.log(commonCharacterCount('geeksforgeeks', 'platformforgeeks'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause `.concat` does not mutate the string called on, but it returns a new one, do:

```
str = str.concat(s1[i]);
```

or just

```
str += s1[i];
```

Comment: Sorry to downvote ya but this does not have anything to do with the question. concating two strings may be a step for you, but it does not answer the question at all. Could you provide a full example with your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the frequencies of each of the characters and go over this map (char->frequency) and find the common ones.

```
function common(a, b) {
    const m1 = {};
    const m2 = {};
    let count = 0;
    for (const c of a) m1[c] = m1[c] ? m1[c]+1 : 1;
    for (const c of b) m2[c] = m2[c] ? m2[c]+1 : 1;
    for (const c of Object.keys(m1)) if (m2[c]) count += Math.min(m1[c], m2[c]);
    return count;
}
```