# How to count the number of same occurring characters in a string

Tags: javascript

I am having a string like the follows:
 "AABAAABBC"

I need to implement javascript logic to print the following output.

2AB3A2BC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: The suggested duplicate counts characters anywhere in the string, according to its sample output OP wants to count consecutive characters

Answer (score 3):

Using `replace`

`(.)\1+` [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/JhMUlZ/1)

```js
var str = 'AABAAABBC'

var res = str.replace(/(.)\1+/g, (match, p1) => match.length + p1)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: that is a thing of beauty