# Check if a string contains 3 underscores with Regex

Tags: regex

I need to check if a string variable contains three underscores "_". Fewer or higher amount of underscore should be false. How do I do that?

Comment: Why regex? Regular expressions are fantastic for doing a number of things, but this type of character counting can be done simpler with other tools. What language are you using?

Comment: Just split by `_` and check count of array elements to be `4`

Comment: `^(?:[^_]*_){3}[^_]*$`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript). In PHP use `substr_count` (please always mention what environment you're working with and what you have tried and didn't work).

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. For the ones saying "why use Regex?" - First of all, that was, obviously, not the question. Client wants to use Regex, otherwise I could easily have solved it with array-operations. But that's not the point.

Answer (score 1):

`^(?:[^_\n]*_){3}[^_\n]*$` should do the trick - [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8YBIP4/1/)

This regex is inspired by [ctwheels' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308966/check-if-a-string-contains-3-underscores-with-regex/59309226#comment104820564_59308966), with the added change that newlines are included in the negated capture group to ensure that this regex does not match across multiple lines.

- `^(?:[^_\n]*_){3}` Starting from the beginning of the string, match any characters that aren't newline or underscore, then one underscore - and repeat this three times.
- `[^_\n]*$` match non-underscore or newline characters to the end of the string.