# Is there a way to return the frequency of a character in a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

e.g
count("Good", "o")
result: 2

I'm not looking for it to be fast, I just need something that is simple and works.

Comment: `String.prototype.match`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` to find occurrences of a character in a string and create an array of the matches. Using `.length` will tell you how many. The `'g'` flag in the `RegExp` is used to match **all** occurrences and not just the first.

```
function count(str, find) {
    return (str.match(RegExp(find,'g')) || []).length
}

count("Good", "o");
```

The `RegExp` solution above does not work if the character you are looking for is a special `RegExp` character such as `.`, `|`, `+`, etc.

The following is an alternative solution which does not use `RegExp` (which is also possibly faster):

```
function count(str, find) {
    return (str.split(find)).length - 1;
}

count("Good", "o");
```

This function splits the string into an array at each occurrence of your character. (Ex. `Good` becomes `['G','','d']`). The size of this array is always one more than the number of occurrences since it includes both ends. Therefore, you can get the length of this array and subtract 1.

Comment: Try to find the number of dots. It doesn't return zero.