# How to count the amount of specifc symbols that a user has entered in a text form

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry if it seems like a newbie question but I was wondering if there was a way to count the amount of specific symbols like a dot or slash in a URL style format that a person has entered.

```
var regex = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[A-Za-z=:.]{1,12}\.[A-Za-z]{1,6}\b([-A-Za-z0-9%_\+=?&//#]){1,250}/
var validx = regex.test(document.getElementById("webname").value);
```

That's the regex and how Im calling the text input. So from that I was wondering if there was a way of counting the amount of symbols a user has entered.

I thought I could just call the function that contained a checker but it does not work

```
function dotcheck()
{
   var dots = detect.webname.value;
   if (dots.indexOf(".") > 0){}
```

the function where I thought you could see/count the amount of dots there

```
if (dotcheck = false){
            messages.innerHTML = 'Safe';
```

the if statement that I used to call the function.

Any help would be appreciated and if there is anything else you would need from me don't hesitate in asking.

Comment: Are you looking to detect the presence of a specific symbol, or are you looking to see how many times a certain symbol occurs?

Comment: looking to see how many times the symbol occurs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I will try it out thank you

Answer (score 0):

The count of any character in a `String` is simply how many matches `String.match(RegExp)` returns.

Since you mentioned periods specifically, and those are special `RegExp` symbols, you can't just write `/./g` for your `RegExp`.  You have to escape it with a `\`, like this:

## `/\./g`

The `g` flag appended to the end means get all matches, not just the first one.

```js
const string = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62008355';
const slashes = /\//g;
const count = string.match(slashes).length;
console.log(count); // 4 slashes
```

```js
const string = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62008355';
const periods = /\./g;
const count = string.match(periods).length;
console.log(count); // 1 period
```