# How to count texts that are the same in a value

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
item_type = 'a, a, b'
```

How can I count the values so I would get something like this:

```
number_of_a = 2
number_of_b = 1
```

I tried something like below but got some JavaScript for input string "[object Object]" error

```
if(item_type != null) {
    item_type = item_type.split(",");
    item_type.forEach(function(x) {
        number_of_a[x] = (number_of_a[x] || 0) + 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: Missing `[x]` in `number_of_a || 0`

Comment: thanks for the heads up @CherryDT. fixed it but still getting javascript error: for input string : "[object Object]" it seems

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce` is your friend, as with any grouping operation

```js
const item_type = 'a, a, b';
const result = item_type.split(", ").reduce ( (a,i) => {
   a[i] = (a[i] +1 || 1)
   return a;
},{})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i've forgotten how useful reduce can be. thanks. works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

If we are interested in only alphabets, improving the @Tamas Szoke  answer.

```js
const str = 'a, a, b'
const chars = {}

for (let char of str) {
  if(char.toUpperCase() != char.toLowerCase()){
    chars[char] = chars[char] + 1 || 1;
  }
}

console.log(chars)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there could be only `a` or `b` you can do it that way:

```js
const item_type = 'a, a, b'

let number_of_a = 0
let number_of_b = 0

if (item_type != null) {
  item_type
      .split(',')
      .map(el => el.trim()) //remove whitespaces from each element
      .forEach(el => el === 'a' ? number_of_a++ : number_of_b++)
}

console.log(`a: ${number_of_a}`)
console.log(`b: ${number_of_b}`)
```

Otherwise you should use an array or an object:

```js
const item_type = 'a, a, b'

const occurrences = {}

if (item_type != null) {
  item_type
      .split(',')
      .map(el => el.trim()) //remove whitespaces from each element
      .forEach(el => {
        if (!occurrences[el]) {
          occurrences[el] = 1
        } else {
          occurrences[el] += 1
        }
      })
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(occurrences)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`)
}
```