# How to find similar elements of string

Tags: javascript

I have stucked with a simple task and don't understand how to make the decision about it. There is one condition - do not use regular expressions. The task is to write a function that counts similar elements of a string so if we have `dddmmmmccccaaamm`, the function returns `d3m4c4a3m2`. Firstly I thought about converting string to array and using `filter` method but it is the wrong way. Now I think to find the first element of the array and compare it with each element in the loop, but don't know what to do next.

Please note, that my question doesn't match [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript)

```js
function countFig(str) {
  let arr = str.split('');
  let newArr = [];
  let a = arr[0];
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if ((i = arr.indexOf(a, i)) === -1) break;
    newArr.push(i); // here Im stucked
  }
  return newArr
}
console.log(countFig('dddmmmmccccaaamm'))
```

Comment: Your example only counts the same characters when they're adjacent. Notice that you have separate `m4` and `m2`. Does that help?

Comment: I don't know how to make a counter which counts the similar figures, moreover it should reset when another figure begins

Comment: Loop over the characters, and just check if the current character is the same as the previous character.

Comment: There's no need to use `split()`. You can index strings just like arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce each character and keep track of previous and count. You can initialize your reducer with the first character and increment the count each time you see consecutive occurrences.

If you run into a character that differs from the previous, reset the `count`, set the `last` to the `curr`, and append to the `result`.

I added the `\b` (backspace escape character) to the end of the array so that it can finish reducing the final sequence of characters. Left-over characters would be thrown away at the end. Now we can return the `result` portion of the reduction.

```js
const countFig = (str) =>
  (([head, ...tail]) =>
    tail.reduce((acc, curr) =>
      curr === acc.last
        ? { ...acc, count: acc.count + 1 }
        : {
            ...acc,
            result: acc.result + acc.last + (acc.count + 1),
            last: curr,
            count: 0
          },
    {
      last: head,
      count: 0,
      result: ''
    }))
  ([...str.split(''), '\b']).result;

console.log(countFig('dddmmmmccccaaamm')); // d3m4c4a3m2
console.log(countFig('abbcccd'));          // a1b2c3d1
```

Comment: I know `reduce()` is fun, but this looks so much more complicated than a simple loop.