# get ratio between sum of same char in a string and the whole string length

Tags: javascript, string

this function should count the "a" in a string and calculate a ratio between the sum of all "a" and the string length. It works fine except when the string is empty and it should output "0" instead of NaN. That'

```js
function ratio(statistic) {
 let charcount = 0 ;
 for ( let i = 0 ; i < statistic.length ; i++){
   
   if ( statistic[i] == 'a' ){ charcount += 1 ;}
    
}
return Math.round(charcount/statistic.length * 100) ;
}
console.log(ratio('abababaabaaa'));
console.log(ratio(''));
// 67
// NaN <---- here should be 0
```

s what I want to fix, thank you.

Comment: You are dividing by 0 when statistic = `""`

Comment: Use `return Math.round(charcount/statistic.length * 100) || 0` since you are dividing by 0 what results in NaN!

Answer (score 0):

when you have empty string or null string, the value of `statistic.length` will be 0. So you are missing of this check in your code that is why you are getting NaN (Not a Number).

```js
function ratio(statistic) {
 let charcount = 0 ;
 for ( let i = 0 ; i < statistic.length ; i++){
   
   if ( statistic[i] == 'a' ){ charcount += 1 ;}
    
}
// Corrected code here 
return statistic.length == 0 ? 0 : Math.round(charcount/statistic.length * 100) ;
}
console.log(ratio('abababaabaaa'));
console.log(ratio(''));
// 67
// NaN <---- here should be 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
function ratio(statistic) {
  let charcount = 0 ;
  for ( let i = 0; i < statistic.length; i++ ) {
    if ( statistic[i] == 'a' ) { charcount += 1; }
  }
  if (charcount === 0) return 0; // check if there were no a's in the string, if so return 0
  return Math.round(charcount/statistic.length * 100) ;
}
console.log(ratio('bbbbbbbaaa'));
console.log(ratio(''));
```

To prevent from having to divide by 0, we just check if no a's were found and if so return 0 then and there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to count the amount of matches for the character that you want. `(statistic.match(/a/g)||[]).length` where you can change 'a' for whatever character [(took from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671743/12468580)

The NaN problems is occurring because if the string length is zero, you're dividing 0/0. That's a mathematical indeterminate form. To fix that you should check first if the string is or not empty `statistic.length > 0`.

```js
let ratio = (statistic) => statistic.length > 0 ? Math.round((statistic.match(/a/g)||[]).length / statistic.length * 100) : 0;

console.log(ratio('abababaabaaa'));
console.log(ratio(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the statistic as a parameter in ratio function is '', *statistic.length* is 0. And this causes mathematical error because something cannot be divided by 0. If you write some exceptional code like following, it will work well.

```
function ratio(statistic) {
   let charcount = 0 ;
   for ( let i = 0 ; i < statistic.length ; i++){
      if ( statistic[i] == 'a' ){ 
         charcount += 1 ;
      }
   }
   return (statistic == ''? 0 : Math.round(charcount/statistic.length * 100)) ;
}
```