# Multiple of letters count in js

Tags: javascript, string

i have a task:
Count the number of letters “a” in text
Count the number of letters “o” in text
Write the result of multiplying the number of letters “a” and “o”.

is it possible to solve this task in a shorter way??

```js
function countString(str, letter) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == letter) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

const string = hello my name is Ola.toLowerCase()
const letterToCheck = "o"
const letterToCheckTwo = "a"

const result = countString(string, letterToCheck);
const resultTwo = countString(string, letterToCheckTwo);


const total = result + resultTwo
console.log(total)
```

Comment: `const string = hello my name is Ola.toLowerCase()` where are the quotes ?

Comment: So pass in an array of values and see if the character exists in the array.

Comment: see if you can generate a dictionary/map of characters along with their count.

Comment: This seems better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (or https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ when taken literally)

Comment: By 'shorter' do you mean 'fewer lines of code'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object that stores the count of all the characters and then you can compute the product using this object.

```js
const str = "Avacado";
const charsCount = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
  str,
  (r, ch) => {
    const lowerCh = ch.toLowerCase()
    r[lowerCh] ??= r[lowerCh] || 0;
    r[lowerCh] += 1;
    return r;
  },
  {}
);

console.log(charsCount["o"] * charsCount["a"]);
```

**Note:** [Array.prototype.reduce](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce) is a generic method, so it can be used with a string as well.

Answer (score 1):

With regular expression function `match()` will output all the matched conditions.

```js
const string = "hello my name is Ola"
const numberOfA = string.match(/a/gi);
const numberOfO = string.match(/o/gi);
console.log(numberOfA.length * numberOfO.length)
```

Comment: This is his task requirement " the result of multiplying the number of letters “a” and “o`` "

Comment: Ah, OP's original code had `+` :) so two reg exp will be needed.

Comment: Yes, maybe he missed that as 2 ( * or + ) 2 = 4

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this using `map` `filter` and `reduce`

```js
const calculate = (string, letters) => letters
  .map(l => string.split('').filter(c => c === l).length)
  .reduce((res, item) => res * item)


const string = 'hello my name is Ola'.toLowerCase()

console.log(calculate(string, ['a', 'o']))
console.log(calculate(string, ['a', 'o', 'e']))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different approaches. In this post I've programmed in a way that allows you to expand to different letters, different amounts of letters, and different strings easily. There may be better approaches if your problem never needs to change.

In your current code, your are traversing the strings twice and counting the occurrences of the letter within them. You could easily pass the function an array and only traverse the string once:

```
function countString(str, letters) {
  //rather than being a character, letter is now an array of characters
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (letters.includes(str.charAt(i))) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

const string = "hello my name is " +  Ola.toLowerCase()
const lettersToCheck = ["o", "a"]


const result = countString(string, lettersToCheck);

//iterate over the array to get the total
var product = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
   product *= result[i];
}


console.log(product);
```

Rather than iterating over the strings, however, a different approach is to use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and `.match()`. This approach has fewer iterations, although I'm not sure about the low level efficiency, since lots of the comparison is encapsulated by `.match()`:

```
function countString(str, letters) {
  //iterates over the array of letters rather than the string
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
  count += (str.match(new RegExp(letters[i], "g")) || []).length; 
  }
  return count;
}

const string = "hello my name is " +  Ola.toLowerCase()
const lettersToCheck = ["o", "a"]


const result = countString(string, lettersToCheck);

//iterate over the array to get the total
var product = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
   product *= result[i];
}

console.log(product);
```

If regex is too much, you could also use `.split()` to iterate over the characters rather than the string:

```
function countString(str, letters) {
  //iterates over the array of letters rather than the string
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
  count += str.split(letters[i]).length - 1;
  }
  return count;
}

const string = "hello my name is " +  Ola.toLowerCase()
const lettersToCheck = ["o", "a"]


const result = countString(string, lettersToCheck);

//iterate over the array to get the total
var product = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
   product *= result[i];
}

console.log(product);
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript) for more information

Comment: wow, there are many options to solve this problem, I only thought of one solution, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the letter frequency each time the phrase changes and then request the product by specifying the letters in the frequency map.

```js
const letterFrequencyMap = (str) =>
  str.toLowerCase().split('').reduce((acc, k) =>
    acc.set(k, (acc.get(k) ?? 0) + 1), new Map);

const computeProduct = (freq, ...keys) =>
  keys.reduce((product, k) => product * (freq.get(k) ?? 1), 1);

// Main

const phrase = "It's about to be noon in a bit.";
const freq = letterFrequencyMap(phrase);

// a = 2; o = 4
console.log(computeProduct(freq, 'a', 'o')); // 8
```

Comment: reduce is very difficult for me to understand,thank you very much, I will study your solution